# File Upload in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm currently using Entity Framework Code First approach for my asp.net MVC3(aspx syntax) project.

I have a model in my project called `EmployeeModel`

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string imageinfo;
    public string fileinfo;
}
```

My DbContext is

```
public  class ContextDB:DbContext
{
     public DbSet<EmployeeModel> Employee { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have a file browser for both `fileinfo and imageinfo`  in my view to upload the files and images and the path of the files and images need to be stored in the database.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why are you going to save files in Db? What about `Drives`.???

Answer (score 0):

In `Asp.Net MVC` we have to use `HttpPostedFileBase` for Uploaded files as shown below :-

**Controller :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
 if (file != null)  // file here will have your posted file which you post from view
 {
    int byteCount = file.ContentLength;   <---Your file Size or Length
    byte[] yourfile = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(yourfile , 0, file.ContentLength);
    var doc1 = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Default.GetString(empfile);
    // now doc1 will have your image in string format and you can save it to database.
 }
}
```

**View :**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
 <input type="file" name="file" />
 <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: but how do i bind it to my model and upload to database?

Comment: @user3894583...no need to bind with model ..just see my updated ans.

Comment: @Exception, you are exceptional in copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

Try using

.chtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // This action renders the form
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // This action handles the form POST and the upload
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
        {
            // extract only the fielname
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("Index");        
    }
}
```